# 3d plotting with basemap

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf

I'm trying to make the following atmospheric 3d visualization code but i get error

```
ax.quiver(x[skip],y[skip],z[skip],u[skip],v[skip],vadv[skip], length=0.1, normalize=False)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

this my link data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDrcZAsMwJrbgaJwASSz07dSnVSpfJKK/view?usp=sharing

```
# load necessary packages:
import os
import conda

conda_file_dir = conda.__file__
conda_dir = conda_file_dir.split('lib')[0]
proj_lib = os.path.join(os.path.join(conda_dir, 'share'), 'proj')
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = proj_lib

import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import sympy as sp
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pandas as pd

print('this worked')

# open netcdf file
nc = Dataset('D:/dataskripsi/medan_17_2021/nc/18.nc') 

# Check file
print(nc) 

itime = 26 # time step to calculate and plot

#defenisi parameter
u = nc.variables['u'] [0,:10,:17,:29] #[ # Zonal wind [m/s]
v = nc.variables['v'] [0,:10,:17,:29] #[itime, :, :] # Meridional wind [m/s]
#tmpk = nc.variables['t'][itime, :, :] # temperature [K]
rv = nc.variables ['vo'] [0,:10,:17,:29] #[itime, :, :] # relative vorticity
vv = nc.variables ['w'] [0,:10,:17,:29] #[itime, :, :] # vertical velocity
gp = nc.variables ['z'] [0,:10,:17,:29] #[itime, :, :] # geopotensial
#hgh= nc.variables ['level'] [:] # pressure level
lon= nc.variables ['longitude'] [:] # bujur
lat= nc.variables ['latitude'] [:] # lintang



#derivative
gradtx = np.gradient(rv.shape,u.shape)
gradty = np.gradient(rv.shape,v.shape)
gradtz = np.gradient(rv.shape,gp.shape)

#calculation parameter
hadv = -(u.shape*gradtx + v.shape*gradty)
vadv = -(vv.shape*gradtz)

#defenisi 3d plotting
#x = lon
#y = lat
#z = hadv.shape

x,y,z =  np.meshgrid(lon,lat,vadv)


#Create 3d normal figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,14))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

#Draw the earth map using Basemap
# Define lower left, uperright lontitude and lattitude respectively
extent = [95, 102, 2, 6]
# Create a basemap instance that draws the Earth layer
bm = Basemap(llcrnrlon=extent[0], llcrnrlat=extent[2],
             urcrnrlon=extent[1], urcrnrlat=extent[3],
             projection='cyl', resolution='l', fix_aspect=False, ax=ax)

# Add Basemap to the figure
ax.add_collection3d(bm.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(bm.drawcountries(linewidth=0.35))
ax.view_init(azim=300, elev=50)
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude', labelpad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude', labelpad=20)
ax.set_zlabel('VADV', labelpad=20)


# Add meridian and parallel gridlines
lon_step = 5
lat_step = 5
meridians = np.arange(extent[0], extent[1] + lon_step, lon_step)
parallels = np.arange(extent[2], extent[3] + lat_step, lat_step)
ax.set_yticks(parallels)
ax.set_yticklabels(parallels)
ax.set_xticks(meridians)
ax.set_xticklabels(meridians)
#ax.set_zticks(d)
#ax.set_zticklabels(d)



skip=(slice(None,None,1),slice(None,None,1))
ax.quiver(x[skip],y[skip],z[skip],u[skip],v[skip],vadv[skip], length=0.1, normalize=False)
ax.set_zlim(0., 150)
plt.show()
```

i expect the result of 3d modeling from vadv and hadv parameters. This parameter expect can modeling cloud microphysics

Comment: Weclome to SO. It is best to provide a minimal reproducible example to make life as easy as possible for people to read and answer your question. Please remove comments etc. and redundant line spacing. The code is too difficult to follow as it is